# Jquery replace character and apply classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several string in the following format

```
<span class="label">20€</span>
```

And want to convert it all to something like this:

```
<span class="label">20<small>€</small></span>
```

How could I achieve this in Jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It works, but is affecting other strings that doesn't have the €
>   character. I mean other spans with the same class, it changes the
>   first letter or those strings. Figure I have other strings with this
>   syntax: `<span class="label">request price</span>`

**HTML:**

```
<span class="label currency">20€</span>
```

**Note 1:** Added additional class currency to identify the span that needs to be modified.

**Note 2:** Use a span instead of small as all styles elements are re purposed. (Thanks @David). Read more info @MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/small

You can use replace function like below,

```
$(function () {
    $('span.label.currency').html(function(i, v) {
       return v.replace('€', '<small>€</small>');
    });
});
```

Comment: `small` isn't deprecated (which surprised me, when I was looking for a reference), though it *has* been 'repurposed': https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/small.

Comment: @DavidThomas You are right.. I always thought it was deprecated. Thank you.

Comment: Oh, me too! The only reason I discovered that it wasn't is because I was trying to provide a reference to say that it *was*. Which, to be honest, back-fired horribly! =D

Comment: @DavidThomas hahaha.. :) .. Thanks for the pointers and I liked your answer better.

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest:

```
$('.label').html(function(i,h){
    return h.replace(/([^\d+])/,'<span class="small">$1</span>');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ggL9h/).

Bearing in mind that I'm choosing to use `span` with a class of `small`, rather than a `small` element.

Under HTML 5, though, remember that the `small` element is:

> repurposed to represent side-comments and small print, including copyright and legal text, independent of its styled presentation.

[Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/small](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/small).

If the currency symbol is predictable, you could explicitly replace the `€` character (rather than using the above to replace, essentially, 'not-numbers'):

```
$('.label').html(function(i,h){
    return h.replace(/(€)/,'<span class="small">$1</span>');
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ggL9h/1/).

Or, assuming the currency symbols are known in advance, you could specify the symbols to be replaced (using regular expressions again, though):

```
$('.label').html(function(i,h){
    return h.replace(/([€£$])/,'<span class="small">$1</span>');
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ggL9h/2/).

References:

- [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/).
- [Regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
- [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Comment: Definitely more elegant with regex.

Comment: It works, but is affecting other strings that doesn't have the € character. I mean other spans with the same class, it changes the first letter or those strings.

Figure I have other strings with this syntax:
<span class="label">request price</span>

Comment: I don't like the Regex, this is very situational and can easily introduce future bugs. You should just replace € not everything thats not a number.

Comment: Thank you all. The solution that worked for me is below (Vega). I should have explained better my question.